# Deserialize single structure field using Protobuf .net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a question regarding deserialization using Protobuf .Net.  I am trying to replace XMLSerializer with it and I cannot find a way to deserialize single field from file.
I need information if file was modified, which is one of the fields in saved structure.

Is it even possible ? If yes, can I ask for some help?

Regards

Comment: In this case I think it would help people arriving at the question if you post some of the `XMLSerializer` code you're starting from as a base for answering with protobuf.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most cases, frankly you can just deserialize the entire thing - it'll be fast, etc. However, if you *really* want to limit it, there are a few options.

The simplest is to just *create a smaller model*, with just the information you want on it. So: if your original model has 46 fields on it, 5 of which are collections etc - but you just want the `Version` which is in field 12, then:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class InsertNameHere {
    [ProtoMember(12)]
    public int Version {get;set;}
}
```

now deserialize *that*:

```
var obj = Serializer.Deserialize<InsertNameHere>(source);
int version = obj.Version;
```

This will work because protobuf-net is *contract* based; it doesn't have to be exactly the same type, as long as it looks close enough. A more advanced approach, though, would be to use `ProtoReader`:

```
int version = 0;
using (var reader = new ProtoReader(source, RuntimeTypeModel.Default, null))
{
    int field;
    bool keepReading = true;
    while ((field = reader.ReadFieldHeader()) > 0 && keepReading)
    {   
        switch (field)
        {
            case 12:
                version = reader.ReadInt32();
                // STOP LOOPING (leaves the stream partly-read)
                keepReading = false;
                break; 
            default:
                reader.SkipField();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

The reason you might want to use the above is that it can *stop looking earlier* - i.e. as soon as we have found our field 12, we can kill the reader without processing the rest of the file. Normally, I would only use the second approach if we know the data is large, and we don't want much of it.

There is a slight gotcha in that *technically* protobuf is an appendable format, so *in theory* there could be another "field 12" right at the end of the file. By the speficication, it is "last value wins", so short-circuiting in the above *could* (in theory) give you a different answer. HOWEVER! This is very very unlikely, and you would usually *know* if you are taking advantage of appended messages. This simply DOES NOT APPLY to most people.